# One RDP session time off by 6 minutes compared to server time

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, time

We have a customer with a Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Server.

When we log onto the server via RDP as User1, the time in the RDP session matches the time of the server.

When we log onto the server via RDP as User2, the time in the RDP session is six minutes faster than the server clock.  This occurs regardless of the PC used to log into the server.

How can the time in one user session be six minutes off from the server clock?  I didn't even think this would be possible.

I can't find anything online about this issue.  If it was a timezone issue, it seems like the clock would be off by one hour.  In this case, User1, User2, and the PC used to connect are all set to EST.